# Issue sending POST request from Swift

Tags: json, swift

Essentially I need to send a POST request to an API that is looking for the parameter value for `"value"` I have a variable in my Swift app that is called testPOST that contains the value the API is looking for:

I am having trouble understanding why the following code is not working?

```
fileprivate func fetchJSON(){
    var urlString =  URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://example.com/example/example.php")!)
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
    urlString.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "value=\(testPOST)"
    URLRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to fetch data from url", error)
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                // Swift 4.1

                self.structure = try decoder.decode([ScheduleStructure].self, from: data)

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            } catch let jsonError {
                print("Failed to decode json", jsonError)
            }

        }
        }.resume()
}
```

UPDATE:

I don't get any error messages, but I also don't receive any JSON data back, ScheduleStructure is the codable struct I have but it doesn't seem to be read.

import UIKit

```
struct ScheduleStructure: Codable {
    let customer: String
    let PickedUpNUM: String
    let DeliveryNUM: String

}
```

I just need a way to POST a value to the API and have it return JSON data.  The only issue I am having is sending the data from the app and having it return data.

Comment: "not working" as in crashing or getting an error back or...?

Comment: Multiple errors: `Cannot convert value of type 'URLRequest' to expected argument type 'String' ` and `Use of unresolved identifier 'request'; did you mean 'URLRequest'?`

Comment: This seems to be a simple task but I'm having problems with the syntax

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I would really appreciate your help

Answer (score 3):

Change the beginning of your function to

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/example/example.php") else {
    return
}
var request =  URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let postString = "value=\(testPOST)"
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, _, error) in
```

You created your url object twice and treated the request as a string

Comment: @Rob Thanks. That was an oversight on my part

Answer (score 1):

You should feel free to accept [Joakim’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56480567/1271826) which identified the syntactical issues, but I wanted to make another observation. Specifically your request will fail or not work properly if `testPOST` contains any reserved characters (e.g. space, `&`, `+`, etc.). Unless you know that `testPOST` can never contain any such characters, should percent-encode the value when building your request, e.g.:

```
func fetchJSON() {
    guard
        let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/example/example.php"),
        let value = testPOST.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)
    else { return }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = "value=\(value)".data(using: .utf8)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // ...
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Where

```
extension CharacterSet {
    static let urlQueryValueAllowed: CharacterSet = {
        let generalDelimitersToEncode = ":#[]@" // does not include "?" or "/" due to RFC 3986 - Section 3.4
        let subDelimitersToEncode = "!$&'()*+,;="

        var allowed = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
        allowed.remove(charactersIn: generalDelimitersToEncode + subDelimitersToEncode)
        return allowed
    }()
}
```

BTW, it’s also best practice (though often not required) to set a few headers, specifically `Content-Type` (specifying how the request is encoded) and `Accept` (how the client expects the response to be encoded).

```
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```

Your web service is obviously not considering these headers, but many web services do. Plus, it makes the intent of your code explicit.